# Personalizing Content

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

i have a usecase where i want to personalize the content, that a visitor see based on his 
information saved in Audience Manager.(i have added a keyword "personalize" for one of the contact "x").For this

I have created a a target group, defined its characteristics and tracking keys(defined personalize > 0).

After this, i associated the Target group with a component presentation and Published the Page

When i logged in with "x" credentials i was unable to see that component presentation on the Page.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

First steps:

1. Validate the user has the value for personalize in the Broker DB
2. Check you have the WAI module in your web app
3. Look at the published page, and validate the conditions are in the output
4. Check your target type is set to an appropriate language (not none)
5. Check your storage bindings are correct in Deployer and web app

If that reveals nothing, please update your post with more info.

Finally, consider posting this at: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/grant-beta-access?key=63880f9cbf452c62f726770209533893