# Can we add "select all" checkbox for selecting the multiple checkboxes on Tridion component using Extensions

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-worldserver

Just to confirm, whether if we can have a new checkbox "Select All" on the components of the Tridion Translation, the objective is here that we have got lots of languages and business user want to select all on single click. I know these fields are read-only, however just checking whether we can have some type of extensions to achieve this or any other suggestion is always welcome.

Please see below screen shot, with the new "Select All" checkbox.

[image: Transalation Manager Component]

Comment: This should be logged as an enhancement request, perhaps you can build it as an Extension? Also, you should really be using http://tridion.stackexchange.com for Tridion-related questions...

Comment: @NunoLinhares, that SE site is still in *private* beta.

Comment: See Chris' answer here to join the fun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195518/personalizing-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Alexandra Popova, Product Manager for SDL:

Hi Manoj,

This checkbox makes perfects sense since the list of Target Languages can be pretty big. The feature has been already requested (registered as an Enhancement Request) but was not yet implemented.

There is a possibility to create a plugin that will set checkboxes to unchecked when the screen is loaded. Plugin can be also coded to selectively check some publications and not others (based tcmuri). There is a hotfix (Test Track #82766) that needs to be applied prior to plugin - please check with SDL Support if you are interested.

BTW I see your publication names do not show up properly for Chinese (PRC) for example: there is a workaround for this issue:

The width of a column can be changed in TranslationJob.aspx - the table with ID TargetsTable. Notice that any changes made will obviously be overwritten by any new hotfix/version delivered by us so it's not fully supported changing it:) Also notice IIS reset is needed as IIS caches the compiled ASPX file.

Comment: thanks for your reply!! any idea when we could we get some hotfix for above issue from SDL Tridion, I will check with SDL support for above plugin whether we can use it or not also thanks for pointing for increasing the size of column, I will give try for it and update the answer accordingly